# Accessing Dictionary element for a tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, tableview

I have passed a dictionary to a second view controller and assigned it to an array, I thought I could access the data easier this way:

```
var myAlerts: NSDictionary!
```

The dictionary has three elements for each: Id (which I don't care about), alertDate, and alertNote.

I'm trying to get these elements into a tableView but struggling with this.

I thought about just moving it into two arrays and accessing it that way, cumbersome but it at least gets me further down the road so to speak.

Here is the raw data from the dictionary AFTER it was past to the second controller:

```
{
    alerts =     (
                {
            alertDate = "2017-07-16";
            alertNote = "Rob is the worlds greatest friend";
            id = 2;
        },
            {
        alertDate = "2017-07-17";
        alertNote = "This is a test of the emergency system";
        id = 1;
        }
    );
}
```

When I tried to move the values into two arrays with this:

```
func CreateArray() {
    for i in 0...myAlerts.count {
        alertsDate[i] = myAlerts["alerts"]["alertDate"]
        alertsNote[i] = myAlerts["alerts"]["alertNote"]
    }
}
```

I get the proverbial Type Any? has no subscript members.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Beth.Iarson1977 your alerts response is [[string:Any]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myAlerts` with that data is now a dictionary containing an *array* of dictionaries. (so top level is a dictionary, with one key/value pair which is of type array of [String:Any] objects).

Since a dictionary value is of type Any, it can't infer in this case what the type of the value for the key `alerts` is. So you have to try cast it to a specific type first, in this case an array of dictionaries, i.e. [[String:Any]]

So this should get rid of your error:

```
func CreateArray() {
    for i in 0...myAlerts.count {
        let alertArray = myAlerts["alerts"] as! [[String:Any]]
        alertsDate.append(alertArray[i]["alertDate"] as! String)
        alertsNote.append(alertArray[i]["alertNote"] as! String)
    }
}
```

Note: I had to change alertsDate and alertsNote arrays to using append as in my demo code i had no existing items in the array and using and index would have caused an error.

Comment: that worked, thank you Jay - now I just need to figure out how to get it in the tbleView LOL so far that's still kicking my fanny.